# how to edit javascript content assist proposal in eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

For example,in the js file,when I type
`window.al`
the eclispe's content assist solution will come up with a winodw shows
`window.alert`
`window.alert("")`
but I just want the `window.alert("")`one,so anytime I will have to use the down key to select the one I want
and this proposal is from **"basic proposal"** as it in the follow images
Is there any way that I can edit the **"basic proposal"** so that I can remove the `window.alert` and let that just contain `window.alert("")`?

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will find content assists in Window->Preferences->Javascript->Editor->Templates.

Comment: I think "Templates" can just setting the template proposals in the "advanced" setting, but I want to set the "basic proposals",thanks.